# postman request works with no problem but when executing my test.js file i get a 404

Tags: node.js

I have an issue with a request to an API that I try to build but I get a 404 in node js when executing my test.js file.

Error:

```
HEADERS: {"date":"Sun, 18 Oct 2020 17:23:18 GMT","server":"Apache","scs-request-id":"c4b2baae-64da-423e-9356-7533f9489b28","content-type":"application/json","content-length":"178","connection":"close"}
BODY: {"status":"404","code":"INVALID_REQUEST_RESOURCE","message":"The requested resource does not exist. Verify that the resource URI is correctly spelled.","error":"invalid_request"}
```

this is how my test.js file looks like:

```
var https = require('https');

const options = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials' },
    auth: 'user:pass',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 443
};

const requ = https.request('https://consent.swisscom.com/o/oauth2/token', options, (resp) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${resp.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(resp.headers)}`);
    resp.setEncoding('utf8');
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});

requ.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
requ.end();
```

when I execute the test.js file by running node test.js I get the above-mentioned error.

if I do a postman request there is no problem.

it seems to me like node.js wants to perform a GET instead of a POST as I instruct it to.

can you advise?

thanks

Comment: Is the URL `'https://consent.swisscom.com/o/oauth2/token'`  correct ? Is the server API expecting some parameters to be sent, read the docs maybe

Comment: Can you try to use `axios` fro instance?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee: this was also my first thought but I checked it with my postman and it is the same.

Comment: @Anatoly: i used already 2 packages. request (i know it is deprecated sice February) and https gave me the same result

Comment: You can try exporting a sample code in axios node.js from postman to compare what parameter you are missing

Comment: i exported from postman:"url": {
     "raw": "https://consent.swisscom.com/o/oauth2/token",
     "protocol": "https",
     "host": [
      "consent",
      "swisscom",
      "com"
     ],
     "path": [
      "o",
      "oauth2",
      "token"
     ]

Comment: it looks ok to me :(

Comment: Look at https://gist.github.com/akexorcist/ea93ee47d39cf94e77802bc39c46589b maybe this thread helps you

Comment: thanks, it worked with axios but it would be also interesting what the problem was on my example.